# ValueError when applying function on each value of a multi-indexes dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, multi-index

I have the following dataframe and I would like to apply a function for each value :

```
             A       B        C
GROUP       Prod   Prod     Prod
DATE            
2020-07-21    0      0        0
2020-07-20    0  -132,568 232,934
2020-07-19    0      0        0
```

I tried :

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x : x/1000 if x!=0 else x)
```

But it gave me :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: `np.where(df!=0, df/100, df)`

Comment: thanks @yatu but what if I want to keep the df structure ? i applied pd.DataFrame to your answer but it resets indexes and columns names / levels

Comment: `df[:] = np.where(df!=0, df/100, df)`?